# Select last products of all sales in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this item table stored in SQL Server database:

```
ID_Item   | ID_Sale  | ID_Product |
1         | 200      | 2314       |
2         | 200      | 3894       |
3         | 200      | 4949       |
4         | 100      | 9389       |
5         | 100      | 9499       |
6         | 300      | 9388       |
```

And I need get the last record of the "ID_Sale" column. Those records as follow:

```
ID_Item   | ID_Sale  | ID_Product |
3         | 200      | 4949       |
5         | 100      | 9499       |
6         | 300      | 9388       |
```

I am trying this code, but it fetches only one record:

```
Select Top 1 * From Itens 
Where ID_Sale = 200
Order by ID_Item Desc
```

How to get the results iterating over the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID_Item, ID_Sale, ID_Product 
FROM Tbl
WHERE Id_Item IN
         (
             SELECT Max(Id_Item) Id
             FROM Tbl
             WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
             GROUP BY Id_Sale
          )
```

If you use SQL SERVER 2005+

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT ID_Item, ID_Sale, ID_Product, ROW_NOUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Sale ORDER BY ID_Item DESC) RN
   FROM Tbl
   WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)
SELECT ID_Item, ID_Sale, ID_Product
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Great! Now, can you post how i make it with one date period? I have one column named DateTime and his type is DateTime. Thanks!

Comment: It is not good idea to use data type name and reserved words at all as column name. See edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can Simply Use This Query

```
    select * from Item where ID_Item in(
select MAX(ID_Item) as ID_Item from Item group by ID_Sale)
```